# Image not updating

Tags: angular

I need to update an image, so I did it simply by changing .png file in images folder.
Expected it to be working :)
...\Client\assets\images\faqs\edit-delete-alert.png

This url shows me old image:
http://localhost:4488/assets/images/faqs/edit-delete-alert.png

Here is a new file:
http://localhost:4488/Client/assets/images/faqs/edit-delete-alert.png

I have already restarted iis, and reset chrome's cache, run this alient npm run build but it did not help.
Sorry, I am not UI dev, still need to fix it somehow :)

Thanks,

Slava

Comment: I could find the same image file in assets, and dist folders, so I replaced it and it worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.